# select many-to-many relationships with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

i have 3 tables
post,tags,tags_relationship

```
post:
  post_id, post_title....
tags:
  tag_id, tag_name...
tags_relationship:
 tag_rel_id, tag_rel_post_id, tag_rel_tag_id
```

how do i select all of the posts with tags in single column with (tag1,tag2,...) format for each post via the tags_relationship table?

Comment: could you post an example of some data in the tables and what you expect as output?

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below, don't put it in the question.

Answer (score 6):

**Answer, so the question can be closed.**

SOLUTION FOUND

---

```
SELECT 
    p.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) tagged 
FROM 
    tags_relation tr   
    INNER JOIN posts p ON p.post_id = tr.rel_post_id   
    INNER JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id = tr.rel_tag_id 
GROUP BY 
    p.post_id
```